# Creating a .desktop file for wine applications

Tags: wine, 20.04, .desktop

I'm trying to create a **.desktop** file for a **.exe** file, here's what I made:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=wine /opt/MyApp/MyApp.exe
Name=MyApp
Icon=/opt/MyApp/data/icons/MyApp.ico
```

I have the icon in the menu but when I run it, nothing happens.
If I try to run the command from the terminal, it works just fine - but from the menu it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from ExamView Pro. Kubuntu 18.04.4 and Wine 3.0.1

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ExamView Test Generator
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/acer/.wine" wine-stable C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/acer/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/ExamView\\ Pro\\ Test\\ Generator/ExamView\\ Test\\ Generator.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=C274_evpro.0
StartupWMClass=evpro.exe
```

[image]